# How to show the units of the numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code that converts Cartesian coordinates to ellipsoidal coordinates and it works but some variables are in degrees and some of them are in meters. I have to show the difference but I don't know how.

```
def ell2xyz(latitude,longitude,ellHeight):
    import math
    a=6378137.0000
    b=6356752.3141
    e=(math.sqrt(((a**2)-(b**2))/(a**2)))
    N=a/math.sqrt((1-((e**2)*(math.sin(latitude)**2))))
    x=(float((N+ellHeight)*math.cos(latitude)*math.cos(longitude)))
    y=(float(N+ellHeight)*math.cos(latitude)*math.sin(longitude))
    z=(float((1-e**2)*(N+ellHeight))*math.sin(latitude))
    return x,y,z

latitude,longitude,ellHeight=ell2xyz(41.00000000,29.00000000,500.0000)
print(latitude,longitude,ellHeight)
```

Comment: not quite sure what you're asking, in python a `float` has no units

Comment: You will have to manually `print` the text labels you want after each numeric value. Python won't do that for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the [format](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-examples) method

```
print("{} degrees {} degrees {} meters".format(latitude,longitude,ellHeight))
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is all your variables (latitude, longitude and ellHeight) are floats, which are simply numbers. An unit is an abstraction that makes sense for us humans, but your code has no way of knowing what are the units you wish to work with. I believe you merely want to show the units on the screen. In order to do that, you have to manually tell what is what.

Any of the following will work the same:

```
print(latitude, "degrees,", longitude, "degrees,", ellHeight, "meters")
print("{} degrees, {} degrees, {} meters".format(latitude, longitude, ellHeight))
print(str(latitude) + " degrees, " + str(longitude) + " degrees, " + str(ellHeight) + " meters")
```

The result will be:

> 4711572.482946889 degrees, 4179837.81128292 degrees, -1005107.7207451101 meters

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list, so you will have both float and string:

```
def ell2xyz(latitude,longitude,ellHeight):
    import math
    a=6378137.0000
    b=6356752.3141
    e=(math.sqrt(((a**2)-(b**2))/(a**2)))
    N=a/math.sqrt((1-((e**2)*(math.sin(latitude)**2))))
    x=(float((N+ellHeight)*math.cos(latitude)*math.cos(longitude)))
    y=(float(N+ellHeight)*math.cos(latitude)*math.sin(longitude))
    z=(float((1-e**2)*(N+ellHeight))*math.sin(latitude))
    if x > 0:
        x = [x,"N"]
    else:
        x = [x,"S"]
    if y > 0:
        y = [y,"E"]
    else:
        y= [y,"W"]
    z = [z, "m"]
    return x,y,z


latitude,longitude,ellHeight=ell2xyz(41.00000000,29.00000000,500.0000)
print(latitude,longitude,ellHeight)
```

Result:
`[4711572.4829468895, 'N'] [4179837.81128292, 'E'] [-1005107.7207451101, 'm']`